# pandoc: Could not fetch http://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/package TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed

Tags: r, pandoc, cran

When running `R CMD check package_0.1.0.tar.gz --as-cran` I see the following warning

```
* checking top-level files ... WARNING
Conversion of ‘README.md’ failed:
pandoc: Could not fetch http://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/package_name
TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,HandshakeFailure)])")) "www.r-pkg.org" 80
```

I can see some answers (e.g. [here](https://github.com/ivelasq/wizehiver/issues/16)) but it seems they are by windows users (I'm on mac). I reinstalled pandoc from [here](https://pandoc.org/installing.html), but after doing so the warning persists.

I am not familiar with pandoc. This warning is the only warning/error/note on the package so it's quite annoying. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Here is the code in `README.md` (I've substituted the package name for ggplot2)

```
[![CRAN_Status_Badge](http://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/ggplot2)](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2)
```

If I change `http` to `https` the error persists but is slightly different

```
* checking top-level files ... WARNING
Conversion of ‘README.md’ failed:
pandoc: Could not fetch https://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/package_name
TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,HandshakeFailure)])")) "www.r-pkg.org" 443
```

Comment: @tarleb I edited to include the contents of `README.md`

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. If I interpret the error message correctly, then the problem is that no TLS connection can be established (even though the request is on port 80, were TLS is not user). What happens if you change `http://` into `https://`?

Comment: @tarleb I will try

Comment: @tarleb a very similar error (I have included above)

Comment: Huh. What happens if you run `curl -L -o ggplot2-badge.svg 'http://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/ggplot2'`? Do you get a valid image in `ggplot2-badge.svg`?

Comment: @tarleb yes. The `svg` file opens in sublime text but I can see it's preview is the badge as expected. It's also an image as expected when viewing the url in the browser. Also, if I go to the `http` address it redirects to the `https` address.

Comment: I'd double-check that you are using the latest pandoc (also from R). Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @tarleb really appreciate the help. I am out of ideas too. I have removed the badges (for now, simply to avoid warnings) and have also raised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346524/workaround-to-allow-badges-in-package-readme-md-on-github-but-not-in-cran-versio) question

Comment: Can you run the conversion with pandoc directly (without R)? What pandoc version are you on?

Comment: Same problem for me with pandoc last version just installed on debian

Comment: @iago I think this problem happened to me because I had not added the readme to the buildignore

Comment: @tarleb Do you know the typical location of pandoc for R? (I just ran `which pandoc` and I see, `/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/pandoc`, which raises my suspicions that installing anaconda messed up which version of pandoc R uses

Comment: I don't know, sorry. But the answer is probably just a quick web-search away.