# Workaround to allow badges in package README.md on github but not in CRAN version

Tags: r, r-package, cran

`R CMD check packagename_0.1.1.tar.gz --as-cran` produces a `WARNING` if badges are present in `README.md`. This causes consequences like travis CI to fail (since it treats warnings as errors)

Is there a workaround to get the check to pass without removing the badges?

Here is an example of the `WARNING` I see

```
* checking top-level files ... WARNING
Conversion of ‘README.md’ failed:
pandoc: Could not fetch https://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/bigrquery
TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,HandshakeFailure)])")) "www.r-pkg.org" 443
```

Related: [pandoc: Could not fetch http://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/package TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345077/pandoc-could-not-fetch-http-www-r-pkg-org-badges-version-package-tlsexception)

Comment: Can you provide the exact WARNING message you get? I do not receive a warning from `R CMD check --as-cran` with badge links in `README.md` -- see, for example, my [RcppDist](https://github.com/duckmayr/RcppDist) package.

Comment: @duckmayr sorry for the delay. I have updated with an example.

Comment: do you need the README in the CRAN version?  I put it .in `.Rbuildignore` ... (as commented by @user5783745 in the linked question)

Comment: Your analysis is somewhere between plain wrong and faulty. It is not the badges creating issues, is the URLs pointed to.  And yes, I have that too _at times_ but it is generally transient.  But, long story short. if you want to be sure to avoid just remove the URL (and maybe the badge).  I am quite happy with a set of badges across my packages.

Comment: @BenBolker I have the reader.md in buildignore. Actually, if I clone the bigrquery repo directly from gibhub, build from source, then run the check as cran, I see the warning. I am starting to think perhaps this is due to some anomaly on my computer, perhaps I have another (older) pandoc version or something.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel if I visit the urls they seem to display the image as expected. Also, the check produces the warning every time, not just every now and again (as may be explained if the server hosting the images was down for maintenance or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months on, I discovered the problem. When I installed anaconda, it changed the version of pandoc my system used - `which pandoc` should return something like `/usr/local/bin/pandoc` (and not like `/Users/st/anaconda3/bin/pandoc`).

In my case, I edited by `.bash_profile` to exclude ananconda, closed and reopened the terminal and everything worked. (I also reinstalled pandoc from [here](https://pandoc.org/installing.html), but I don't think that had anything to do with fixing it - it did show me the default installation location though)

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to embed (static) badges in pages. They do not auto-update. The purpose is to avoid offline derived errors.

Take a look at readme files in:
https://gitlab.com/ferroao/idiogramFISH. This also handles errors while installing with devtools in windows, a process that does not have online connectivity (see vignette index.Rmd). Look at DESCRIPTION also if you want to see dependencies and vignette builders.

Generate the .md from the .Rmd (Rmarkdown).